# Spliting directory path in UNIX bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am learning UNIX bash shell scripting and struggling with splitting a directory path.

e.g. `/home/sample/test`

I want to get permissions for all the directories in the path. Following is the sample output.
e.g.

```
r w x   r - x   r - x   /
r w x   r - x   r - x   home
r w x   - - x   - - x   sample
r w x   r - x   r - x   test
```

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: This might help: `stat --printf "%A" /home`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a job for `namei` (comes with `util-linux`):

```
namei -m /home/sample/test
```

- `-m` would get the permission modes

Also check `man namei`.

**Example:**

```
% namei -m /etc/passwd
f: /etc/passwd
 drwxr-xr-x /
 drwxr-xr-x etc
 -rw-r--r-- passwd
```